# Syntax Error when calling the name of a model's layer in captum

Tags: python, pytorch, syntax-error

I'm trying to use the gradCAM feature of captum for PyTorch. Previously, I asked the question of how to find the name of layers in pyTorch (which is done using model.named_modules()). However, since getting the names of the modules (my model name is 'model') I have tried to use it with LayerGradCam from captum and am receiving a syntax error - it seems to always happen on the 'number' within the model name.

I import the function with:

```
from captum.attr import LayerGradCam
```

I'm a bit of a Python newbie, so I've tried calling both:

```
layer_gc = LayerGradCam(segmentation_wrapper, model.dl.backbone.layer4.2.conv3)
```

and:

```
layer_gc = captum.attr.LayerGradCam(segmentation_wrapper, model.dl.backbone.layer4.2.conv3)
```

The error message I get is:

```
  File "gradCAM.py", line 120
    layer_gc = LayerGradCam(segmentation_wrapper, model.dl.backbone.layer4.2.conv3)
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is really stumping me, so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Attributes can't be numbers. Try `[2]` instead of `.2`

Comment: Why isn't this in the documentation for us beginners! I'll give this a go!

Edit: No error! Would you like to submit as answer so I can mark as correct for others?

Comment: @Alex well, the [doc](https://captum.ai/api/layer.html#gradcam) says that `layer` must be a `torch.nn.Module` and you tried to provide the name of the module (which is a string, and you did it without quotes, hence `SyntaxError`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array or list indexing is done using `[]` syntax, not `.`.

```
model.dl.backbone.layer4[2]conv3
```